# Why static data member is showing this error?

Tags: c++, static-members

I was learning static data members in c++ and I wrote this code but on compilation, it is giving me this error:

> main.cpp:21:12: error: ‘int Test1::a’ is private within this context

```
 Test1::a=50;
        ^
```

> main.cpp:17:5: note: declared private here
> int Test1::a;

But I don't know why this error is coming and how to solve this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test1{
    static int a; //declaration
};
int Test1::a; // definition

int main()
{
    Test1::a=50;
    cout<<"a= "<<Test1::a<<endl;
}
```

Comment: `static` is a red herring. Unless specified explicitly, everything in a `class` is `private` by default. `static` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @tobias: Alas incorrect on both counts. 1) It is a definition, 2) You can in some circumstances, e.g. access checks are not made with template specialisations. The second point comes in handy when writing unit tests.

Comment: Fair enough, removed my incorrect comment. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You declared `static int a` as private member in the class, which can be accessed only within class. Class members are private by default. You should have declared it as public.

```
class Test1{
public:
    static int a; //declaration
};
int Test1::a=0;
.
.
.
.
//whatever
```

Comment: As we know the value of static data members, once initialized cannot be changed, but if I declare this in public, I am able to change the value.

Comment: The value of static data member cannot be changed only if it declared as const.